# JCheckBox prevent changing checked status when click on text

Tags: java, swing, jcheckbox

`JCheckBox` it is inherited from `JToggleButton`, so clicking on text will have same effect of clicking the checkbox. But now I need a `JCheckBox` which behaves like this:

- Clicking on checkbox: check or uncheck the checkbox;
- Clicking on text: don't update the checkbox, but emit an `ActionEvent`.

Currently I am using a ugly hack by overriding the `processMouseEvent()` function in `JCheckBox`, and only propagating it to `super` if the mouse is clicking on left part of the `CheckBox`. The code is like this:

```
public class MyCheckBox extends JCheckBox {

    @Override
    protected void processMouseEvent(MouseEvent e) {
        if (e.getX() < this.getHeight()) {
            super.processMouseEvent(e);
        } else {
            this.fireActionPerformed(new ActionEvent(this, 0, "click on text"))
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a more straightforward solution?

Comment: *"Currently I am using a ugly hack"*  You're trying to implement some ugly user interface (in terms of usability), so perhaps that is a hint not to do this at all!

Comment: Maybe a tooltip to alert the user that the text is clickable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a JCheckBox without text and a separate JLabel for text with own listener.

Comment: in a wicked (against the poor users of that unusable monster construct ;-) mood?